# How do I sort ActiveAdmin CSV table by id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export-to-csv, activeadmin

How do I sort the table in my ActiveAdmin export file by id? Currently, it is in descending order and I would like it to be in ascending order. I tried the following and it did not work:

```
csv do |organization|
   column :id, sortable: 'organizations.id'
end
```

Comment: how are CSV and organization related and what exactly is your query that you want to sort?

Comment: First sort the list in ActiveAdmin by id and then click on CSV download link.

Answer (score 0):

By default this orders in ascending: `organizations.order(:id)`

OR

```
organizations = your_query
organizations.order( 'organizations.id ASC' )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in ActiveAdmin `csv_builder.rb` you will see `build` calls `controller.find_collection` so try something like:

```
controller do
  def find_collection(options = {})
    request.format == 'csv' ? scoped_collection.order(:id) : super
  end
end
```

TL/DR you can override and customize any of the methods in `data_access.rb` in your controller block.